# How to deserialize not standard datetime in xml

Tags: xml, datetime, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize some response I got back from a service call. However, the response contains some datetime format thats not standard. Its throwing The string '13:37:53 Feb 29, 2012 PST' is not a valid AllXsd value. I am wondering if there is way I can change my xmlreader or something so I can deserialize this?

```
<TimeCreated xsi:type="xs:dateTime">13:37:53 Feb 29, 2012 PST</TimeCreated>
<TimeUpdated xsi:type="xs:dateTime">13:37:53 Feb 29, 2012 PST</TimeUpdated>
```

This is the code I am using to deserialize.

```
    public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
    {
        T result;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (TextReader txReader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            // Create XmlReaderSettings
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
            settings.IgnoreComments = true;

            // Create a new NameTable
            NameTable nt = new NameTable();

            // Create a new NamespaceManager
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);

            // Add your namespaces used in the XML
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            // Create the XmlParserContext using the previous declared XmlNamespaceManager
            XmlParserContext ctx = new XmlParserContext(null, nsmgr, null, XmlSpace.None);

            // Instantiate a new XmlReader, using the previous declared XmlReaderSettings and XmlParserContext
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(txReader, settings, ctx);

            result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Also I am working in windows phone, so i need to a solution available the silverlight running on windows phone.

Comment: I assume you can't just say "It is a non-standard service so we won't play with it"?

Comment: If you don't really need the date time value you could just parse it as cdata which will be ignored by the parser. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: I need the datetime values, but the deserialization has problem.